# migrate from jdk 14 to jdk 16

Tags: java, migrate

soon we are moving from jdk14 and start using jdk16.Ours is desktop application. What measures I need to take to make sure it works correctly on clients machine? Right now some of them using JRE4 and some JRE6.Server- Solaris.

PD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this: [Java SE 6 - Compatibility with previous versions](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/compatibility.html), this document describes possible compatibility issues with Java 5 and Java 1.4 in detail.

You should be able to run your existing class files without recompiling (Java SE 6 is binary compatible with previous versions), but there may be a number of minor issues.

You might also have a number of minor issues when compiling your source code on JDK 6.

Answer (score 2):

enum is now a reserved work. Make sure you check all your code for "enum".

Answer (score -2):

There should be none as the JRE is backwards compatible.

If you are going to compile using jdk16, you may see some deprecation warning that indicate you are using some old objects / methods and that you should refactor to using the newer ones in 1.6.

Comment: Wrong, I guess you had no variables named enum in your code. Or you have not gone through the exercise.

Comment: @Romain, technically he's right:  The **JRE** is backwards compatible.  Of course the **Java Compiler** is not, which is what's going to complain about `enum`.  Mind you, I've seen a whole lot of code break between 1.4 and 1.6...